# Hide filtered items in Azure DevOps Taskboard

Tags: team-foundation-server

We use the Microsoft Azure DevOps Server (on premise) and if I try filtering in the Boards/Sprints/Taskboard for Tasks, States, naming, .. the `Filter` only highlights the results. The rest is still shown.
Is there a possibility to do hide the cards that do not match the filter criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of a built-in solution, but using Chrome (and very likely other browsers too) you can inject the following CSS to hide filtered tiles:

```
.tbTile.tile-dimmed {
    display: none;
}
```

I use the following extension for this: [CSS and Javascript Injection](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-and-javascript-inject/ckddknfdmcemedlmmebildepcmneakaa)

Comment: This is also a workable solution until Microsoft has a "working solution". Because [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/350929/azure-devops-unable-to-hide-users-in-iteration-tas.html) does not work.